# TARGET attribute in Fortran subroutines

Tags: pointers, fortran, fortran90

(I used ifort 19.0.5.281)

In following test code, in `move_association` I take POINTER as INTENT(IN) and check its association state, and change its association to local variable `array(4,4)`.

```
module mod_test

    implicit none

contains

    subroutine write_matrix_2d(a)

        implicit none
        real, intent(in) :: a(:,:)
  
        ! local variables
        integer :: i, j

        do i = lbound(a,1), ubound(a,1)
            write(*,*) ( a(i,j), j = lbound(a,2), ubound(a,2) )
        enddo
  
    end subroutine

(*) subroutine move_association(a)

        implicit none
        real, pointer, intent(inout) :: a(:,:)

        ! local
        real, target  :: array(4,4)

        array = -1

        if ( associated(a) ) then
            print *, "POINTER is associated"
            a => array
        else
            print *, "POINTER is NOT associated"
            a => array
        endif

    end subroutine

end module

program test

    use mod_test

    implicit none

    real, dimension(3,3), target  :: ct(3,3)
    real, dimension(:,:), pointer :: cptr(:,:)

    ct = 1
    !cptr => ct(2:3,2:3)

    write(*,*)
    write(*,*) 'ct'
    call write_matrix_2d(ct)

    write(*,*)
    write(*,*) 'cptr before'
    call write_matrix_2d(cptr) 

    write(*,*)
(*) call move_association(cptr)

    write(*,*)
    write(*,*) 'cptr after'
    call write_matrix_2d(cptr)

    write(*,*)
    if ( associated(cptr) ) then
        print *, " cptr associated "
    else
        print *, " cptr not associtated "
    endif

end program
```

At glance, I thought there should be some problem since Fortran automatically deallocates subroutine's local variable at the end of it making `cptr` to loss its target. But unexpectedly `cptr` survived and also its association state is checked as "associated" as the following output.

```
 ct
   1.000000       1.000000       1.000000    
   1.000000       1.000000       1.000000    
   1.000000       1.000000       1.000000    
 
 cptr before
 
 POINTER is NOT associated
 
 cptr after
  -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000    
  -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000    
  -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000    
  -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000      -1.000000    
 
  cptr associated
```

I suppose there might be additional rules such that local `target` variable inside subroutine automatically gets `save` attribute and so on, is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status of your pointer at the end is `undefined`. You are not allowed to inquire the association status of a pointer with undefined status, it contains some garbage. The garbage happens to be your local array that is no longer valid. You have to nullify it or associate it yourself before any further inquiry.

See also [http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#5](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/%7Eszymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#5)

Comment: Then ```cptr``` well printing ```-1```s and ```associated``` at the end of output is some 'undefined' behavior invoked by using pointers in the wrong way?

Comment: @SANGJUNLEE  Yes, the pointer status is undefined. You are not allowed to use its status and ask for its status. It is undefined, because its target was a local variable that is not valid outside of the subroutine.

Comment: One is allowed to inquire of the association status of an undefined pointer.  One isn't allowed to inquire of the association status of a pointer when its association status is undefined. (That is, pointer definition and pointer association definition are not the same thing.)

Comment: @francescalus I didn't want to dig into the details in language lawyer level words and hopefully used the level suited to the level of the question.